# Filter tuples in list of lists [Haskell]

Tags: list, haskell

I have a list of lists of tuples:

```
let list = [[(1,(2,2)),(0,(3,2)),(0,(4,2))],[(0,(2,3)),(0,(3,3)),(0,(4,3))],[(0,(2,4)),(0,(3,4)),(0,(4,4))]]
```

I would like to filter them by the first value of each tuple.
That's what I tried...

```
compute :: Matrix -> Coordinates -> Matrix
compute m (x,y) = filter (\(a,(_,_)) -> a /= 1) [row | row <- list]
```

with

```
type Matrix = [[Int]]
type Coordinates = (Int, Int)
```

That's the error I got:

```
ContiguousRegion.hs:20:36:
Couldn't match expected type ‘[Int]’
            with actual type ‘(Integer, (t0, t1))’
In the pattern: (a, (_, _))
In the first argument of ‘filter’, namely
  ‘(\ (a, (_, _)) -> a /= 1)’
In the expression:
  filter
    (\ (a, (_, _)) -> a /= 1) [row | row <- checkAround m (x, y)]

ContiguousRegion.hs:20:58:
Couldn't match type ‘(Int, (Int, Int))’ with ‘Int’
Expected type: [Int]
  Actual type: [(Int, (Int, Int))]
In the expression: row
In the second argument of ‘filter’, namely
  ‘[row | row <- checkAround m (x, y)]’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

How can I solve this?
Thanks!

Comment: `compute` do nothing with `m` and `(x, y)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's take a few steps to simplify the `compute` function and figure out the problem:

1. First of all, `[row | row <- list]` does nothing, it's equivalent to just `list`, so we can remove it and replace it with `list`, to make the function easier to read:

   ```
   compute m (x,y) = filter (\(a,(_,_)) -> a /= 1) list
   ```

   By the way, in your message I see that `list` isn't what the argument to filter is actually called. Instead, it's a `checkAround m (x, y)`, so `compute` should probably look like this:

   ```
   compute m (x,y) = filter (\(a,(_,_)) -> a /= 1) $ checkAround m (x, y)
   ```
2. The function you're passing to `filter` is unnecessarily complicated, we can replace it with `\(a,_) -> a /= 1` or even `(/=1) . fst` to make it less noisy. Doing that gives us:

   ```
   compute m (x,y) = filter ((/=1) . fst) list
   ```
3. I'd say it's now much easier to see the problem. Your `list` has the type `[[(Int, (Int, Int))]]`, ie. it's a list of lists of tuples.

   But the predicate your passing into `filter` is expecting a tuple, therefore `filter` itself is expecting a list of tuples.

   This is an obvious type mismatch. How do we solve this? I don't know, that's up to you, but I guess you want to filter the inner list.

   How do we do this? Well, we need to go through each of the inner lists, filter them and put the filtered ones in a new list. This is exactly what `map` (or `fmap`) can help us with. Let's map the filter we've constructed over `list`:

   ```
   compute m (x,y) = map (filter ((/=1) . fst)) list
   ```
4. Unfortunately, the above still gives us a type error:

   ```
   Couldn't match type ‘(Integer, (Integer, Integer))’ with ‘Int’
   Expected type: [[Int]]
   Actual type: [[(Integer, (Integer, Integer))]]
   ```

   Well, why is that? We know that the `Actual type` is the type of `list` and the type of the filtered list as well, but what is the `Expected type` and why is it a `[[Int]]`?

   The answer lies in your type signature, `Matrix -> Coordinates -> Matrix`. `compute` is supposed to produce a list of lists of `Int`s, but we're filtering something a bit different.

At this point I don't really know what you'd like to do, so I'll just end here, but I suspect you either need to change `compute`'s type signature or you need to somehow merge `m` with the filtered results to create a new matrix.

Comment: Following your wise explanations, I ended up writing compute `m (x,y) = map (filter ((/=1) . fst)) (checkAround m (x,y))` using `checkAround m (x,y)` (as you noticed) which returns a `type CMatrix = [[(Int, (Int, Int))]]`. 
Very clear and explanatory, thank you @f4st!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
type SparseMatrix = [Row]
type Row = [Element]
type Element = (Int, Coordinates)
type Coordinates = (Int, Int)

removeRowVal :: Row -> Int -> Row
removeRowVal row i = filter ((/= i).fst) row

removeSMVal :: SparseMatrix -> Int -> SparseMatrix
removeSMVal sm i = [removeRowVal row i | row <- sm]
```

Even if your `list` is not some kind of oddly structured sparse matrix representation, I think the final result is what you described.

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1: Your definition of `compute` refers to `list`, but `list` is not a parameter.

Problem 2: If you change `list` to `m` your code is correct, but the type signature you gave is not correct.

Solution:

Change `list` to `m`, and don't give a type a signature:

```
compute m (x,y) = filter (\(a,(_,_)) -> a /= 1) [row | row <- m]
```

Now ask `ghci` what the type signature should be:

```
ghci> :t compute
compute
    :: (Eq a, Num a) => [(a, (t2, t3))] -> (t, t1) -> [(a, (t2, t3))]
```

Now you see that that `type Matrix` should be defined as

```
type Matrix = [ (Int, (Int,Int) ]
```